# No Video - Not Booting (But micro SD partition changed)

Tags: raspbian

My PI B+ is not booting and no display.

I already tried 3 kinds of power adapter and 2 micro SD cards.

Still the same result, but the SD card partition changed when I check it in my PC.

I use ps vita power supply as my PSU and Toshiba 16GB Class 10 memory.

Comment: How are you sure that it is not booting? Others have reported that their Pi is not working with HDMI but with composite video. Depending on your distribution there might also be some network services open (eg `ssh`, `dhcp`) - if it is connected to a local network it might be reachable. So my question is how did you determine that it is not running?

Comment: I waited For about 10 mins and nothing happen.Should I wait more?I use Noobs 1.3.10 and the latest version of Raspbian.No its not connected on a network.I use pocket wifi.I will connect the PI when i finish it.Don't have router.

Comment: The Power LED is On while the ACT LED is blinking at first but then it will fade after few seconds.

Comment: Booting shouldn't be taking 10 minutes... What kind of display is connected? What else is connected via USB?

Comment: i remove the usb wifi,usb reciver for the move and keyboard.i use HDMI cable for the display.

Comment: ACT LED is blinking very faint.

Answer (score 3):

When I got my Raspberry B+ a few days ago, I had to add/uncomment

```
 hdmi_force_hotplug=1
```

to the config.txt, which is located on the sd-card.

To check whether the Pi is booting correct without a display, you could set the wifi-settings manually with a static ip adress and ping your pi from another computer.

Comment: (hdmi_force_hotplug=1) should copy this in config.txt?and erase the other words in there?

Comment: Just add to `/boot/config.txt` do not erase the other words in there, except of course there is a line reading `hdmi_force_hotplug=<somethingsomething>`

Comment: Please vote up to thanks and click accept button if this fixed your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> Still the same result, but the SD card partition changed when I check it in my PC.

I am not entirely sure what u mean but I think you mean that the micro sd's files or format have changed if so I suggest you check out https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/noobs.md and if you find some iso of noobs or raspian you can see https://www.balena.io/etcher/